# is there a way to delete files on a device using a cordova-based mobile app?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, mobile

I've declared a "filesystem" for my app using window.requestFileSystem.  Shouldn't there be a way for me to delete files within this directory?  I searched for cordova file deletion extensions and didn't see any, so I'm hoping for something html5/javascript-based.

Comment: You can try using the "cordova-plugin-file" plugin for file deletion.

Comment: I checked the docs at https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#persistent. I don't see anything about file deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like the one below :

```
 var path = "file:///storage/emulated/0";
 var filename = "myfile.txt";

 window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path, function(dir) {
   dir.getFile(filename, {create:false}, function(fileEntry) {
     fileEntry.remove(function(){
          // The file has been removed successfully
       },function(error){
          // Error deleting the file
       },function(){
       // The file doesn't exist
      });
    });
 });
```

Source : http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/28/how-to-delete-file-with-cordova